# How to get the value of dropdownlist on selection changed inside the repeater.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have four column inside the repeater, Expected , Accpet , DDL & one Panel which is not visible on page load

If Expect column value and dropdown  selection value is same then only I want to visible that panel otherwise not.

Please help me I am not getting the value of dropdownlist beacuse on selection change whole repeater is refilling not a single value I am able to get.
Can anyone help me for this.

Any possible way will do for me.

**CSS**

```
<style>
        .main
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .inner
        {
            width: 90%;
        }
        .fst
        {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
        .scnd
        {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
        .thrd
        {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
        .frth
        {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }

        .reset-this
        {
            clear:both;
        }
    </style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="fst">
                Except
            </div>
            <div class="scnd">
                Accpet
            </div>
            <div class="thrd">
                DDL
            </div>
            <div class="frth">
                Panel
            </div>
            <div class="reset-this">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="reset-this">
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="fst">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Expected") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="scnd">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("accpet") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thrd">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="50"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="51"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="52"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="53"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="100"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="frth">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Succesful"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reset-this">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDAtaset();
    }

    public void GetDAtaset()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("warehouseTable");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Expected", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("accpet", typeof(string)));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Expected"] = "100";
        dr["accpet"] = "50";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1["Expected"] = "50";
        dr1["accpet"] = "25";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Panel)(e.Item.FindControl("panel1"))).Visible = false;
    }

    protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Panel pnl_active = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("panel1") as Panel;

            Label Expected = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            DropDownList DDLValue = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;

            if (DDLValue.SelectedItem.ToString() == Expected.ToString())
            {
                pnl_active.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do couple of things:

First, add this in your `Page_Load` method to avoid resetting the Repeater's values:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetDAtaset();
    }
}
```

Next, modify the `DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged` method to be like this:

```
protected void DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        Panel pnl_active = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("panel1") as Panel;

        Label Expected = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        DropDownList DDLValue = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;

        //You need to compare the SelectedItem.Text with the label Expected.Text
        if (DDLValue.SelectedItem.Text == Expected.Text)
        {
            pnl_active.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you were comparing the DDLValue.SelectedItem with the label Expected, which is not correct because you need to compare the **DDLValue.SelectedItem.Text** with the label **Expected.Text**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but if i am deebugging then i found that selection changed event is not getting fired.

Comment: even after adding (!IsPostBack) in page_load it still not firing?